# how to get full host name from a partial string in php

Tags: php, web, dns, hostname, no-www

I have a the following URL:`google.com`.

I need to know if the full hostname consists `www`, or a function that will give me the full hostname (IE. www.google.com)

I want to get the full host-name and i cannot always add `www` as a prefix (IE.  if i have `docs.google.com`, i don't want to add `www` because it will destroy the link).

Is there a way to know if i can add `www` as a prefix or not?
I tried some of the PHP `gethost()` functions but no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by "full hostname"?  Depending on how a site's DNS is set up `example.com` and `www.example.com` could be two completely different IPs/sites.  (Heck, I could do `www.sub.example.com` if I wanted to.)  If the link is `example.com`, then I'd just leave it as `example.com`.  Why do you want to know if you can add `www`?

Comment: cause i am using curl for a site and it doen't load resources well if i am fixing relative url to "example.com". on the other hand if i am fixing relative urls to "www.example.com" everything works like a charm. is it possible to get the dns setup for a url?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do here?  The *real* issue is probably elsewhere.

Comment: i am using Curl scrapper for a site of exmaple.com. in order to present it locally in an iframe i am fixing all relative urls (IE - "/image/123.jpg" to "http://example.com/image/123.jpg"), this results in inconsistent behaviors regarding loading images. sometimes i get 503 for some images. BUT when i am fixing the relative URLs to a Full ones (IE - "http://www.example.com/image/123.jpg") i get no errors. so, for a given url i want to knwo what is its full host name.

Comment: The problem is that *both* `http://example.com/image/123.jpg` and `http://www.example.com/image/123.jpg` *are* "full" URLs.  There may be a redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com` which is happening when the page is loaded.  What you'll need to check for is a "Location" header (or another type of redirect).

Comment: i thought there is a better way than that but thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is.  If we use `google.com` as an example, both `google.com` and `www.google.com` have A and AAAA records, but if you try to access `http://google.com`, you get a 301 response and a redirect using a header of `Location: http://www.google.com/`.